# creating a simple map of key/value pairs from an AR result with RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

The JSON I am trying to build is pretty simple - it's a map of Categories to available Products belonging to each Category. It should look something like:

```
{
   category_permalink : [<product 1>, <product 2>],
   another_category   : [<another product>, <yet another>]
}
```

And a Category has_many Products so can be fetched in the controller like

```
Category.where(:permalink => params[:selected_categories]).includes :products
```

But, RABL seems to really want to wrap everything in an array. I've tried many different variations, including stuff like

```
 collection @categories
 node do |cat|
   { cat.permalink => partial('products/product', :object => cat.products) }
 end
```

This is close, but wraps the whole result in an array, and gives me N one-element arrays for each category.

The reason I want this JSON is it would really work well with the front-end app that is pulling this query. Anything else would mean some ugly hacks at the JS-level.

I know I don't have to use RABL for this either, but it's kind of a standard on this app and I'd like to see if it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Classic case of pulling hair and then solving 10min after asking the question out loud. Guess I forgot I was still using ruby...

```
@categories.each do |cat|
   node(cat.permalink) do
      partial('products/product', :object => cat.products.active)
   end
end
```